# jQuery Animate multiple selectors

Tags: jquery, refactoring

I'm not even sure how to phrase this question. The code below has the desired effect I want, but it's completely redundant and ugly, and I'm not sure how to make it a little more elegant. I've tried a while loop without success. Maybe a recursive function or is there a better way to do this?

```
function next() {

$('#scroll_wrapper li:first-child').animate({
  'top' : -elemHeight-offSet
}, {duration: 1000, queue: false, complete: nextDone});


$('#scroll_wrapper li:nth-child(2)').animate({
  'top' : offSet
}, { duration: 1000, queue: false });

$('#scroll_wrapper li:nth-child(3)').animate({
  'top' : offSet2
}, { duration: 1000, queue: false });

function nextDone() {
  var d = $(this).detach();
  d.appendTo('#scroll_wrapper ul').css({'top' : elemHeight+100});
}


}
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
var next = function(){

    var nextDone = function(){
        var d = $(this).detach();
        d.appendTo('#scroll_wrapper ul').css({'top' : elemHeight+100});
    }

    var animateElement = function( element, top, callback ){
        $( element ).animate({
            top: top
        }, { duration: 1000, queue: false, complete: callback });
    };

    animateElement( '#scroll_wrapper li:first-child', -elemHeight-offSet, nextDone );
    animateElement( '#scroll_wrapper li:nth-child(2)', offSet );
    animateElement( '#scroll_wrapper li:nth-child(3)', offSet2 );

};
```

Though, arguably it's more complex.

Comment: I like this method more than mine, but I still don't like the 3 animateElement calls. What if I want to add a 4th element, or 5th?